# C# datagridview right click select edit option and data should be displayed in textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

Here is my code for `DataGrid` in C#.  On a right click on a cell, the `ContextMenu` for edit option should be displayed.  But, I am not able to execute the right click action. And also after clicking on edit menu, I should able to show data in textbox. Eg like NotesID should be displayed in textbox1.

```
/*this is for datagrid cell click code*/
private void dataGrid1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     ContextMenuStrip mnu = new ContextMenuStrip();
     ToolStripMenuItem mnuedit = new ToolStripMenuItem("Edit");
     mnuedit.Click += new EventHandler(editToolStripMenuItem_Click);
     mnu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { mnuedit });
     dataGrid1.ContextMenuStrip = mnu;
}

private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGrid1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
    {
        textnotes.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        textclient.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value);
        textdatetime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
        textcombobox.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value);
    }
}

private void EditClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Service edtservice = new Service();
                         edtservice.EditNotes(Convert.ToInt32(textNotesID.Text),textnotes.Text,textclient.Text,textdatetime.Text,textcombobox.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Records Updated");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try firing it on the mouse events

```
 private void dgvReport_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {

     If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right){

         DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvReport.Rows[e.rowIndex];

     }

}
```

Comment: When i right click on cell i can see context menu option as Edit. But when i click on edit i am getting error as ArgumentOUTOFRangeeption was unhandled. Here is the code for that::

Comment: private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (dataGrid1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
            {

                textnotes.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                textclient.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value); }

Comment: use e.rowIndex and e.Column Index to get your row and cell, out of range exception would be selectedRows has no index at the values you specify.